# Закрыть модальное окно после отправки google формы (angular.js)

Tags: angularjs, google-forms

Вот сама форма

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm detailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><img src="../img/closeGreen.png"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
          <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='http://velesmebel.by/#/thanku';}"></iframe>
          <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1WCIEebc_7cMgxunTjQsCSQY-PikDBFfcl6_LJSSGvyE/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
            <input type="text" name="entry.1029528803" value="" aria-label="Ваше имя" aria-required="true" required="" title="">
            <input type="text" name="entry.1891683386" value="" aria-label="Ваш телефон" aria-required="true" required="" title="">

            <input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;4311919038905274687&quot;]">
            <input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="fvv" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="4311919038905274687">
            <button name="submit" value="&#1043;&#1086;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1086;" class="SendFormToGDocs"> Отправить</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

После этого отправляется на thanku.html
Письмо отправлено и уже лежит в гугл-таблице, но остается неприятнейшая деталь - модальное окно

Comment: а где тут angular.js?

Comment: angular в том, что это single-page application - т.е. без перезагрузки страницы, следовательно модальное окно переходя на страницу не закрывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что у вас модальное окно бутстрапа, и jquery вероятно тоже подключен на странице. Вам нужно там, где вы переходите на новый url выполнить закрытие попапа.

```
onload="if(submitted) {window.location='http://velesmebel.by/#/thanku'; $('.detailModal').modal('hide');}
```

Comment: я решил несколько иным способом, но выглядит работоспособно и гораздо проще чем у меня.